# Show that $F(A,B)$ is neither convex nor concave

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis

$$F(A,B)=\log\left[\det(A+BB^{T})\right]-\text{tr}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{x}^{T}_{i}\right) (A+BB^{T})\right]$$

Where fixed column vectors $\mathbf{x}_{i}\in\mathbf{R}^{n}$,
$A\in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive definite,$B\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times r}(0<r<n)$.

Show that $F(A,B)$ is neither convex nor concave.

---

$\text{1.}$ $f(\mathbf{X}) = \log \det(\mathbf{X})$ is concave, where $\mathbf{X}$ is a positive definite matrix;

$\text{2.}$
Since
$$\frac{ \partial \text{tr}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{x}^{T}_{i}\right)\cdot \mathbf{X})\right] }{\partial \mathbf{X}}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{x}^{T}_{i}\right)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{x}^{T}_{i}\right)^{T}+\text{diag}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{x}^{T}_{i}\right),$$ where  $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric and
$$\frac{ \partial^2 \text{tr}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{x}^{T}_{i}\right)\cdot\mathbf{X})\right] }{\partial \mathbf{X}^2}=O_{n\times n}\quad,$$  $\text{tr}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{x}^{T}_{i}\right)\cdot \mathbf{X}\right]$is both convex and concave.

I don't know why  $F(A,B)$ is neither convex nor concave？

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: logdet is concave.

Comment: I think we misunderstood each other. I meant to say, since logdet is concave it already shows $F$ cannot be convex. For example for $B=0$ the function is linear in $A$ plus $logdet(A)$, so concave, and surely not convex.